# Oracle SQL : Retrieve values in BETWEEN clause for Numbers that are listed as VARCHAR type in table definition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Customer's table with the following customer numbers listed as varchar type in the table definition. Although these customer numbers are all numbers but listed as varchar type, how would you use the between clause in this case?

```
Customer     Customer_number
----------------------------
A            100
B            101
C            102
D            103
E            104
F            105
G            106
H            107
```

I get an unexpected output when running

SELECT *

FROM CUSTOMERS

WHERE CUSTOMER_NUMBER BETWEEN 100 AND 105

Comment: What Oracle version do you have? 12.2 has some handy features for this.

Answer (score 1):

You would use:

```
WHERE CUSTOMER_NUMBER BETWEEN '100' AND '105'
```

Note that the comparison will be as a string, so `'1000'` would match.

If you want the comparison as a number, you can convert:

```
WHERE TO_NUMBER(CUSTOMER_NUMBER) BETWEEN 100 AND 105
```

EDIT:

In Oracle 12C you can add a default for a conversion error:

```
WHERE TO_NUMBER(CUSTOMER_NUMBER DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) BETWEEN 100 AND 105
```

Or a `CASE` expression should work as well:

```
WHERE TO_NUMBER(CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(CUSTOMER_NUMBER, '^[0-9]+$') THEN CUSTOMER_NUMBER END ) BETWEEN 100 AND 105
```

Comment: when comparing as a number using to_number() i get the error ORA-01722: invalid number.

Comment: That means that you have values in your `CUSTOMER_NUMBER` column that are not numbers so it is failing to convert that value to a number using the `TO_NUMBER()` function.